# Numba parallel is slower than sequential. How to improve the speed?

Tags: python, performance, time, parallel-processing, numba

I am trying to speed up my code using numba parallel=True, but I find that it is slower when the iterations are very fast. Here is a simplified example of my code:

```
spec = [
    ('value', nb.float64),
]

@nb.experimental.jitclass(spec)
class Counter():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def increment(self):
        self.value += 1

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value


@nb.njit(parallel=True, cache=True, nogil=True)
def sum_counters_sequencial(m):

    result = np.empty_like(m)

    for i in nb.prange(len(m)):
        counter = Counter(m[i])
        counter.increment()
        result[i] = counter.get_value()

    return result
```

I iterate through an array and add a value to it. But I have to do this process a few million times so I thought to parallelize it.

However, according to some sources, numba parallel has some overhead that may affect performance when the loop iterations are very quick or the data size is small. Also, using index arrays to iterate on the data may have significant overhead (memory and performance) and be unnecessary.

So my question is: how can I optimize my code using numba parallel? Are there any alternatives or best practices for parallelizing such code?

Comment: Parallelism has overhead costs.  When each process only does a little bit of work, parallelism tends to be slower because of the overhead.

Comment: "*numba parallel has some overhead that may affect performance when the loop iterations are very quick or the data size is small*" Not exactly: the overhead is mainly the cost to share the work to the threads and wait for them. It is independent of the number of iteration (at least with the OpenMP runtime by default). Having small iterations is not an issue, but having a short parallel loop is. Thus the parallel code should be faster (though it may not scale for other reasons) as long as `m` is big.

Comment: I think this line `counter = Counter(m[i])` is your main problem when it comes to performance (I would forget about classes in this case, or maybe this is just simplified example?). Second thing, you may want to group counters in 1000/10000s and make parallel loop over those groups.

Comment: In general, the initial parallel overhead cannot be avoided. This is a fundamental physical issue imposed by the general relativity : the communication between cores cannot be faster than the speed of the light, cores have a finite size on a 3D space and the synchronization cannot be optimized (weakened). In practice, there is a long path between the cores (because processors are designed to communicate mainly using caches -- typically the L3 which is far from cores and also as a high latency because of its size and its density limited by the price we want to pay).

Comment: Last but not least, how did you profiled the code? The first call include the compilation which is pretty expensive. It should not be included in the benchmark. Parallel numba codes tends to be significantly more expensive to compile.